# retrieve image from database using mysqli php 7

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to retrieve a png image file from the database

Here is the call from within the `<img>` tag inside body:

```
<img src="..\BankLogin\man.php?id=2" style="width:128px;height:150px">
```

Here's the `man.php` file:

```
<?php
   $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","images");
   $imgId = $_GET['id'];
   if (!empty($imgId)) {
   $sqliCommand = "SELECT image FROM images WHERE id = $imgId";
   $result = mysqli_query($sqliCommand,$link);
   $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
   mysqli_close($link);   
   header("Content-type: image/png");
   echo $row['image'];
  }
?>
```

On running the code i just get an image frame with an 'unloaded image'(am i saying it correct?).I am pretty sure something is wrong in the man.php file, maybe in echo $row['image']. I am not sure how to go about making it right. Any help with this would be great.

Comment: that would be an interesting sql injection

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: Are we to assume the image data is in the database?

Comment: How are you saving the images? Does it have a folder path?

Comment: Have you checked what the script actually returns? That's the first thing to check.

Comment: @GeorgeQ yes the data is in the database. Its a png image saved as blob type.

Comment: @AT-2016 i uploaded the image manually in the db using phpmyadmin

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen The script is returning what looks like just the border of the image and an unloaded image icon on the top left corner

Comment: I mean the actual data it returns, not what the browser shows.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen No i havent. I dont know how to.

Comment: @newbie. Have you obtained the output or not as required. Since yesterday itself you told you have got the output. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the image which is stored as BLOB type in phpmyadmin you have to echo it as follows.

```
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $rows['image'] ).'"/>'
```

Example:

To Retrieve the BLOB image from the DB you have to do like this.

```
<?php
$db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbname"); //keep your db name
$query = "SELECT * FROM image WHERE id = $id";
$sth = $db->query($query);
$fetch=$sth->fetch_assoc();
echo '<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,'.base64_encode( $fetch['image'] ).'"/>';
?>
```

For Inserting the image you need to follow the procedure like this So that if you encode it as base 64 you can retrieve the image perfectly without any error.

```
<?php
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","DbName"); //keep your db name
$single_image = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['images']['tmp_name']));
//U have to keep your DB table column name for insertion. I keep image type Blob.
$query = "INSERT INTO image (image) VALUES('".$single_image."')";  
$SQL = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
?>
```

Comment: No, there is no need to encode it when you're just outputting it directly.

Comment: How have you save the image into database. Using BLOB type or what.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen. I accept it. But there is a procedure right to store the BLOB image into DB. For that purpose alone we need to encode it and then display the image.

Comment: If you need to display the png image try using `echo '<img src="data:image/png;base64,'.base64_encode( $fetch['image'] ).'"/>';`

Comment: Only if you want to put it inline you need to encode it. In this case it's not inline and usually there is no reason to inline it.

Comment: @NareshKumar.P The image is stored as BLOB type manually into the db. How am i supposed to encode that image? Or instead of manual input should i just use the code you have mentioned for inserting?

Comment: You use the code what i have mentioned for insert. Since during manual inserting some of the codes may miss match rather you can insert using the code that i have provided.

Comment: @NareshKumar.P okay i will try tht!

Comment: Ya try and let me know. or else i shall guide you the other way.

Comment: @NareshKumar.P It works! Still needs some resizing but it seems to be working after inserting the images using your code! Thank You sir! Anyway, what was the other way?

Comment: @NareshKumar.P Though it works on any other window, it doesnt work when i call it from the img tag in the main program!

Comment: @newbie. I hope so you can retrieve the images using the code that i have provided. If so you find it useful you can accept my answer so that it will be used by the other developer who has the same error too.

Comment: @newbie. How has you called the image tag under the main program. Can you share so that it will be useful for me to pick out your errors.

Comment: <img src="..\BankLogin\man.php?id=2" style="width:128px;height:150px">

Comment: Though callig it from within the main program didn't work, i included it in place of the img tag and now it seems to work fine

Comment: @newbie. if so it work also you will not accept the answer right as correct one right:)

Answer (score 0):

The function `mysqli_close` should be called after the image data is echoed. This is because it destroys the result sets.

Also please fix the SQL Injection vulnerability:

`$imgId = (int)$_GET['id'];`

Comment: Tried both, still nothing! Something else is wrong.